# How to access registration page even after signing in

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a special kind of requirement where the user can not register accounts. Only the admin can view the registration page and register a new account for the user.

I have already implemented a Role-based authentication filter on the RegisterModel: PageModel class and that's why no unauthenticated user(guest) can view the registration page. But when the admin user tries to view the page I am getting Access Denied.

Now how do I enable an authenticated user(Role = "Admin") to view the registration page.

Comment: Can you please add some code examples of your registration page authentication?

Comment: Its the default register.cshtml.cs file that come with ASP.NET Core 2.1 Identity